# Undefined function onClick in contentComponent

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Im trying to access a function inside a button on contentComponent that is inside a createDrawerNavigator. The problem is that the 'props' passed to the contentComponent does not have the function that im trying to access and i keep getting 'undefined'. Here's the code:

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  }, {
    contentComponent: (props) => (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
          <Button
            color='red'
            title='Logout'
            onPress={() => { props.logoutCurrentUser() }}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    ),
})


const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MainDrawer: { screen: MainDrawer},
})

class AppNavigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  logoutCurrentUser = () => {
    console.log("LOGOUT PRESSED")
  }

  render() {
    return <RootNavigator logoutCurrentUser={this.logoutCurrentUser}/>
  }
}
```

The **onPress={() => { props.logoutCurrentUser() }}** is where I get the error. How to properly call this function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed a workaround, I added a mapDispatchToProps with the function that I want to call when clicking the button:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    logoutCurrentUser: () => {
      console.log("LOGOUT PRESSED")
    }
  }
}
```

Then on my **class AppNavigation** i did this:

```
render() {
  return <RootNavigator screenProps={this.props} />
}
```

And my **MainDrawer** I changed to this

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
}, {
  contentComponent: (props) => (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
        <Button
          color='red'
          title='Logout'
          onPress={() => { props.screenProps.logoutCurrentUser() }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
})
```

Leaving the answer here in case someone else also have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The props are basically the "arguments" that you pass to a component, so let's say you have

```
<Component something="abcd" anotherThing="efg"></Component>
```

inside that component if you access to
this.props you would have this

```
{
    something: "abcd",
    anotherThing: "efg",
}
```

so you could do this.props.something or this.props.anotherThing and you could access these values.

You could also do something like this in your method

```
const { something, anotherThing} = this.props;

console.log(something);
console.log(anotherThing);
```

So what it's wrong with your code is that you are not passing logoutCurrentUser function as a prop.

you need to pass it to the component

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  }, {
    contentComponent: (props) => (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
          <DrawerItems {...props} />
          <Button
            color='red'
            title='Logout'
            onPress={() => { props.logoutCurrentUser() }}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    ),
})

class AppNavigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  logoutCurrentUser = () => {
    console.log("LOGOUT PRESSED")
  }

  render() {
    return <MainDrawer logoutCurrentUser={this.logoutCurrentUser} />
  }
}
```

If you want pass a prop using a HOC just pass the prop to the HOC, an HOC it's like for example a stacknavigator

```
const SomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  // config
});

<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

Comment: one last question, if I have my MainDrawer inside a stackNavigator (i'll update the question), how I'd pass this props? Because i'm returning only the stackNavigator on render()

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: so it would go like this:  
  render() {  return <RootNavigator screenProps={this.logoutCurrentUser} />  } But i still cant access 'props.logoutCurrentUser()' on my MainDrawer

Comment: no screenProps it's just a sample name
in your case it would be
logoutCurrentUser={this.logoutCurrentUser}

Comment: still no success, sorry, same error: props.logoutCurrentUser is not a function~ undefined (i updated the question with what I have right now)

Comment: if i put a console.log(props) inside the onClick() the logoutCurrentUser is not visible aswell

Answer (score 0):

```
class AppNavigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logoutCurrentUser = this.logoutCurrentUser.bind(this);
  }

  logoutCurrentUser = () => {
    console.log("LOGOUT PRESSED")
  }

  render() {
    return <MainDrawer logoutCurrentUser={this.logoutCurrentUser}/>
  }
}
```