# React Navigation pass params to nested stackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, stack-navigator

In react navigation 3.0 they added the feature to pass default params to screen. The problem is that I want to pass those params to a nested stackNavigator but I can't figure out how to do so.
These are my navigators:
MainDrawer.js:

```
    const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
      Anime: {
        screen: SerieNavigation,
        params: { type: "anime" },
        path: "anime/:anime"
      },
      Tv: {
        screen: SerieNavigation,
        params: { type: "tv-show" },
        path: "tv/:tv"
      },
      Film: {
        screen: SerieNavigation,
        params: { type: "film" },
        path: "film/:film"
      }
    });

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

    export default AppContainer;
```

SerieNavigation.js:

```
    const SerieStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Content: {
          screen: SearchScreen,
          params: { type: "anime" } //<-- HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DO SO params: { type: props.navigation.state.params.type }
        },
        Serie: SearieScreen,
        Episode: EpisodePage
      },
      {
        headerMode: "none",
        navigationOptions: {
          headerVisible: false
        }
      }
    );

    SerieStack.defaultNavigationOptions = {};
    export default SerieStack;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To access props of the parent you can use `this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam('type');`
now you can access any prop of the parent.

**EDIT:**

Not sure if this will work with react-navigation v5 but give it a try

Comment: what do you mean of parent  ?

Comment: I had a navigator with a navigator inside, but the props didn't get through the navigators, so to access the props you need to reference the parent ( the navigator at the top)

Comment: Yeah, I got it if I have two AppContainer how to get params from the other screen in separate other AppContainer @LeonardoDrici

Comment: Can you avoid dangerouslyGetParent? by somehow pass params from stack navgiator maybe?

Comment: I call this function from stack where I dispatched from another stack! And this help me! Thank you! "+1"

Comment: `getParam` doesn't seem to be available in react-navigation v5

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could achieve that by passing your screenProps to your stackNavigator.
Like this (assuming you return your stack navigator somewhere):

```
render() {
  <MyDrawerNavigator screenProps={this.props} />
}
```

Then, you can access it inside your **SerieStack** like this:

```
const SerieStack = createStackNavigator(
{
  Content: {
    screen: SearchScreen,
    params: { type: this.props.screenProps.navigation.state.params.type }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't render the stackNavigator I pass it directly as a screen to the drawerNavigator

Comment: it's the same thing, you would pass the props to the drawerNavigator then, i'll edit the answer

Comment: take a look at this question I asked a few days ago, I had the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422419/undefined-function-onclick-in-contentcomponent

Comment: Doing like you said will make my component render the same objects. If you can see all three screens render the same component but based on the params it renders different results .By doing what you provided all the three screens will render the same thing.

Comment: you will pass the main props from your HOC, then you can send them differently to each of your screens

Comment: I get undefined is not an object.

Comment: navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().getParam("type") is undefined?